Abnormal segfault while trying to verify if a vector is empty or not
I have been trying to solve a simple leetcode problem, but it has given me a segfault for one particular test case where the input is essentially empty vectors.
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

vector<int> shortestAlternatingPaths(int n, vector<vector<int>> &redEdges, vector<vector<int>> &blueEdges)
{
    vector<vector<int>> red(n), blue(n);
    for (auto e : redEdges)
    {
        red[e[0]].push_back(e[1]);
    }
    for (auto e : blueEdges)
    {
        blue[e[0]].push_back(e[1]);
    }

    vector<int> dis(n, 1e6);
    dis[0] = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        vector<vector<bool>> vis(n, vector<bool>(n, 0));
        vis[i][0] = 1;
        priority_queue<pair<int, pair<int, bool>>, vector<pair<int, pair<int, bool>>>, greater<pair<int, pair<int, bool>>>> pq;
        pq.push({0, {0, i}});

        vector<vector<int>> edges;

        while (!pq.empty())
        {
            int d = pq.top().first;
            int node = pq.top().second.first;
            bool last = pq.top().second.second;
            pq.pop();

            edges.clear();
            edges = (last) ? blue : red;
            cout<<edges[node].size()<<endl;
            if (!edges[node].empty()) //ERROR - SEGFAULT
            {
                for (auto v : edges[node])
                {
                    if (!vis[!last][v])
                    {
                        vis[!last][v] = true;
                        dis[v] = min(dis[v], 1 + d);
                        pq.push({1 + d, {v, !last}});
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        if (dis[i] == 1e6)
            dis[i] = -1;

    return dis;
}

int main()
{
    vector<vector<int>> redEdges = {};
    vector<vector<int>> blueEdges = {};
    int n = 1;
    vector<int> ans = shortestAlternatingPaths(n, redEdges, blueEdges);
    for (auto i : ans)
    {
        cout << i << " ";
    }
    return 0;
}

I am clueless as to how am I able to print the size of edges[node] and not able to check if its empty or not.
I tried changing some things like storing the size in a variable and using that variable for the if statement
int size = edges[node].size();
if(size > 0){...}

Even with this approach I am getting the same segfault in the if statement even though the size variable shows a value of 0 on the vscode debugger.

Are you sure it is not triggered by node index being out of range ? You can try to run the code with sanitizers enabled, it should give you more information

What blows up is vis[i][0] = 1; for i=1 and n=1. You are accessing a second item of a 1-item vector there. (Source: ran it under gdb)

BTW, Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>? and What's the problem with "using namespace std;"?

n is 1, so vis has one element, and then you go and index it with i which is 1 on the second iteration. And as the old saying goes, undefined behaviour is undefined.

If you change x[i] to x.at(i), you'll get a nice exception when you access the vector out-of-bounds.

There is also another problem - the edges vector is empty, and you are trying to access it with edges[node].

std::vector::operator[] does not have range-checking. Eljay suggested using the at method instead, so that you can check the validity of node as an array index. We're anticipating unpredictable behaviour when you're accessing uninitialised memory.

The first loop assumes that any vectors contained by redEdges are non-empty vectors.   If there is any empty vector in redEdges then e will (on some loop iteration) be a copy of that empty vector, so evaluating both e[0] and e[1] give undefined behaviour.

@molbdnilo But the during the loop it should never get to the vis line as the if statement should skip over it

Where would that be? The assignment vis[i][0] = 1; at the very beginning of the for loop is unconditional.
